# Link a archivo en HTML

Tags: html

Estoy tratando de usar un `href` en un sitio web para abrir archivos que están en otro servidor.

Si introduzco manualmente la dirección en la barra de direcciones, este abre sin problemas.

```
\\180.5.5.555\FilesACIP\Carpeta2\DocumentosCortes\PorTurno\417201907291\BITACORA 290719.pdf
```

al hacerlo el link se muestra así:

\180.5.5.555\FilesACIP\Carpeta2\DocumentosCortes\PorTurno\417201907291\BITACORA 290719.pdf

Cuando le pongo el mismo link a un href

```
<a href="\\180.5.5.555\FilesACIP\Carpeta2\DocumentosCortes\PorTurno\417201907291\BITACORA 290719.pdf">Ver</a>
```

Al darle clic quita y cambia las diagonales, y me termina diciendo archivo inexistente

```
180.5.5.555/FilesACIP/Carpeta2/DocumentosCortes/PorTurno/417201907291/BITACORA 290719.pdf
```

Probé esta otra opción

```
<a href="file://///180.5.5.555/FilesACIP/Carpeta2/DocumentosCortes/PorTurno/417201907291/BITACORA 290719.pdf">Ver</a>
```

Esta abre el archivo, pero para hacerlo el tengo que car clic derecho, abrir en pestaña nueva y en la barra de direcciones darle <kbd>enter</kbd> para que se muestre.

¿Existe alguna solución para esto?

Gracias.

Comment: Al parecer la IP `180.5.5.555` responde a una `computadora`, la cual carece del software para proporcionar el servicio de  `servidor`. Es por esto que el protocolo `HTTP/HTTPS` (_en tu caso omitido al hacer `\\180.5.5.555`_) no esta funcionando

Answer (score 1):

La forma correcta de poner un vínculo a un recurso que se encuentra en una ruta UNC es utilizando el protocolo `file://` seguido de *tres diagonales*, por ejemplo:

```
file://///ruta/a/el/recurso
```

También, la forma correcta de poner vínculos a rutas que tienen *caracteres no imprimibles o especiales*, es realizar la [codificación de la ruta](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp), por lo que tu vínculo debiera ser algo como:

```
<a href="file://///180.5.5.555/FilesACIP/Carpeta2/DocumentosCortes/PorTurno/417201907291/BITACORA%20290719.pdf">Ver</a>
```

En resumen, he sustituido el espacio en el nombre del archivo por `%20`, que es el código porcentual (hexadecimal) del caracter de espacio (dec. 32).

He realizado pruebas con Chrome, Firefox, IE y Edge y funciona en todos. Otra posible explicación para tu problema es que el vínculo esté dentro de un HTML que contiene otros errores. Te sugiero aislar el problema y probarlo, por ejemplo, con un HTML como el que sigue debieras poder ver o descargar el archivo sin problemas:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <title>Prueba</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <h1>Prueba</h1>
    </header>
    <section id="unica">
      <h2>Link</h2>
      <p><a href="file://///180.5.5.555/FilesACIP/Carpeta2/DocumentosCortes/PorTurno/417201907291/BITACORA%20290719.pdf">ver pdf</a></p>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias, esto es la respuesta correcta, aunque mi caso no funciono por restrcciones del servidor. Tuve que usar un return file()(:NET c#(), muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Si estas trabajando con un servidor, podrias darle una mirada a lo siguiente:
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/Manejando_los_archivos
Te puede ayudar con los redirecciuonamientos hacia los mismos. 
En cuanto al abrir el archivo, te hace falta agregar el atributo target, que indica la forma en que se abrira el link (en este caso archivo), como el ejemplo que te doy aca, lo hace en otra pestaña.

Dale una mirada a esto, para conocer los otros direccionamientos:

[HTML  target Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp)

Espero que te sea útil,
Saludos

```
<a target="_blank" href="..\carpeta\archivo" >Descripción</a>
```